# Find and replace values in df column in Pyhton

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a lot of data calculated and stored in a dataframe. A small example from the datatable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsMsu.png)
At first I calculate all the values in the 3th column. After that I want to change every value that is bigger than the value 2. Is there a function where I can find all the values bigger than 2 and replace them by another value?

I can only find a function to replace in a dataframe when a specific value is present, but I can't determine all the values and the location in the column up front.

The function I tried: df.loc[df['Zelfconsumptie'] > 2, 'Zelfconsumptie'] = 2

Comment: Please share a reproducible example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

To find all values in a given column 'Zelfconsumptie' in df that are greater than 2 and set those values = 2 use this:

```
df[df['Zelfconsumptie'] > 2] = 2
```

Comment: I still get the same error as before. It seems like it can't find the column 'Zelfconsumptie'. I get a KeyError: 'Zelfconsumptie'

Comment: @AaronDeWinne then you don't have a column with that name.